# proving n^k = Ω(c^n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

how can we prove

**n^k = Ω(c^n)**

i am trying to go by the definition

**n^k >= some constant * c^n**

but I am unable to get any value for the constant.I mean I am unable to approach the problem properly

****EDIT****

Sorry about the mistake as the function was supposed to be

**n^k = O(c^n)**

Well the main obstacle I am facing is calculating the value of the constant using the 
definition.

Starting with the definition:

step 1: **n^k<= p* (c^n)**

step 2: **(n^k/c^n)<= p**

I am getting stuck here.I am trying to differentiate the functions because as **n-> infinity** its of **infinity/infinity** form but still I am going no where!

To prove the equation

**n^k = O(c^n)**

what methods can we use apart from trying to get a value for the constant?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't true! For example, 2^n grows much faster than n^2.

Comment: @nneonneo thank you.That was stupid of me to ask without checking.

Comment: @nneonneo to prove that n^2=O(2^n) , how can we calculate the value of the constant using the definition?I know this might be a dumb but I am unable to approach properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you differentiate numerator and denominator of `n^k / c^n` k times you get what you want:

```
k! / (ln c)^k * c^n   ->    0  when n-> Inf
```

So not only

```
n^k = O(c^n)
```

but even

```
n^k = o(c^n)
```

Comment: differentiating k times works, I dont know why I didn't even think about it.Thank you.